# Jquery move each elements

Tags: jquery, element, move, cycle

trying to move one element after another with this code:

> $(".elem1")*[i]*.insertAfter('.elem2')*[i]*;

without *[i]*.

Yes, it's working, but... on other pages i have more then 1 same block with the same elements and i'd like to change it everywhere.

I need make a cycle, but I don't know how to do in jquery.

So, the main goal: move one element to another **in each block on the page**.

Comment: well would be better if you could post a reproducible example. however when you say without[i] you could use jquery each http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/  or forEach https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: that being said jquery has some pretty powerful selectors so if you post your code maybe it would be possible to do it in one statement without iteration